# Does PyGithub have a way to make conditional calls?

Tags: python, pygithub

I notice that the `GitHub` API has an `eTag` which can be used to return changes since the tag.  `github3.py` has a way to do this, but I prefer `PyGithub` because it feels more intuitive.

Does this feature exist?  If not, is there another recommended library?

Answer (score 0):

Not right now, unfortunately. EDIT: I could be wrong. Looks like [Add Conditional Request and Data Persistence Support Alternative Solution by akfish · Pull Request #193 · PyGithub/PyGithub](https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub/pull/193) might have added it.

Here are some related issues for that project. Looks like they are looking for contributors. There's only 3 folks in 
 https://github.com/orgs/PyGithub/people as of Mar 2018.

- https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub/issues/26
- https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub/issues/282
- https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub/issues/536

More generally, [Caching Github API calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14886664/caching-github-api-calls) might be helpful to roll your own or use for implementing inside PyGithub.